Python Scripting in Kicad
When do engineers actually use the python scripting feature available in CAD software like KiCAD.
I am designing an amplifier and I am thinking about using a python script to check for max voltage rating of parts and compare them to operating point generated by spice simulation and throw an error if the operating point voltage exceeds the max voltage of the part.
However I am an amateur hobbyist having no experience in the industry.
So how is python scripting is used in practice if it is used at all.

I've used scripting to place locate parts using polar coordinates. That's less necessary now that many tools have snap-to-polar grid. At one time we had to use scripting to get logos onto PCBs with at least one tool!
I would say that generally over time tools tend to absorb whatever you would want to do in  scripting into their functionality. That is part of what causes the tools to bloat over time. And unless you're planning to be a layout professional that mostly works with one set of tools, the percentage of your time you spend using any one tool will be small, so automating tasks is of less benefit than you might think. PSPICE has has 'smoke' parameters that can do more-or-less what you are asking for, and has had them for some time. I don't know how widely they are used. I didn't use them when I used PSPICE.

In the PCB-based system world I rarely find it necessary to simulate more than 10% of a design. Unless you go to a great deal of trouble, simulation only tells you what happens typically, and often the models are idealized in other ways (both for simplicity and so simulations run fast). That's particularly important with things like switching power supplies because the simulator has to accurately model fast waveforms over many, many cycles. I don't think we need a simulator to tell us that a 10V capacitor is adequate voltage rating for a 3.3V rail (and unless you use a sophisticated capacitor model, the simulator won't tell you what really happens with bias, aging and temperature effects- and even then you're not likely modelling the layout parasitics). Predicting what happens on a stressed part with self-heating requires modelling the heat loss etc., not easy to get right, and worthy of serious attention if you want system-level reliability.
That said, it does sounds like a decently 'cool' academic project though. You could probably get an article, a paper or a video out of it depending on how and what you do.

As time has passed, I have settled on doing my best to not customize my software tools as much as practical, as remembering and mainaining these customizations becomes a growing chore.
That being said, there are exceptions, one being a bit of python scripting in Kicad to produce BOM's in the exact format for which my templates expect.  This is so far the only case in Kicad where I have deemed it efficient to do so, to get the results that I need.
#
# KiCad BOM Generator Entry:
# python "snip\Electronics\Library\KiCad\Scripts\ner_bom.py" "%I" "%O"
#
# Example python script to generate a BOM from a KiCad generic netlist
#
# Example: Sorted and Grouped CSV BOM
#

"""
    @package
    Output: Excel (default) or CSV (comma-separated)
    Grouped By: Value, Footprint, P1, P2, P3, Type
    Sorted By: Ref
    Fields: Ref, Quantity, Value, Cmp name, Footprint, Description, Vendor

    Command line (default):
    python "pathToFile/ner_bom.py" "%I" "%O"
    (with variants)
    python "pathToFile/ner_bom.py" "%I" "%O" "autolab" "autoscan" "aldm"

    If you do not want to sort on 'Value' (as is the default), you may append a list of additional
    arguments. A separate BOM spreadsheet will be generated for each argument, with the
    components sorted by the argument name.  The argument name must exist as a schematic
    parameter for every component.

    Like:
    python "pathToFile/ner_bom.py" "%I" "%O" "autolab" "autoscan" "aldm"

"""  



A number of my clients do very similar things: one draws the diagrams with internal part numbers but needs to make BOMs with manufacturer/supplier part numbers, which are chosen from a preference list (ie, internal part 123 has a list of supplier part numbers, the person in charge of production choose which things to buy).  A python script does the necessary adaptation.
